# Taking two separate tibbles(e.g. [[1]] and [[2]]) in data and merge?

Tags: merge, multiple-columns, rename, tibble

**I have a multiple step issue**

1) I need to turn [[1]] "Total" -> Losing_Runs

2) I need to turn [[2]] "Total" -> Winning_Runs

3) I need to take tibble[[1]] "Loser" column and merge up with tibble[[2]] "Winner" column under a new column name labeled "Team"

4) The new tibble should be a 30x3 when compiled. The new column variables should be "Team", "Winning_Runs", "Losing_Runs"

***The R doc below***

```css
[[1]]
# A tibble: 30 x 2
   Loser              Total
   <chr>              <dbl>
 1 Baltimore Orioles    288
 2 Kansas City Royals   278
 3 Chicago White Sox    252
 4 Minnesota Twins      251
 5 Texas Rangers        236
 6 Detroit Tigers       233
 7 Miami Marlins        228
 8 Cincinnati Reds      224
 9 Pittsburgh Pirates   217
10 San Diego Padres     212
# ... with 20 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 30 x 2
   Winner               Total
   <chr>                <dbl>
 1 Boston Red Sox         694
 2 Houston Astros         627
 3 New York Yankees       579
 4 Cleveland Indians      577
 5 Chicago Cubs           572
 6 Oakland Athletics      571
 7 Los Angeles Dodgers    568
 8 Atlanta Braves         543
 9 Washington Nationals   540
10 Milwaukee Brewers      528
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Thank you very much for any&all help!